# How do I install the penmountlpc kernel module?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, compiling, kernel-modules

I would like to install the [penmountlpc](http://users.tkk.fi/~hlinnaka/flybook/) touchscreen driver in Ubuntu 11.10 on a Dialogue Flybook A33i.

When I try installing it using `module-assistant` from the source packed in [penmountlpc-source_1.1_all.deb](http://code.google.com/p/penmountlpc/downloads/list), I receive the following build error (see also the [full build log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/736734/)):

```
# Install the module
cp penmountlpc.o debian/penmountlpc-modules-3.0.0-12-generic/lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic/misc
cp: cannot create regular file `debian/penmountlpc-modules-3.0.0-12-generic/lib/modules/3.0.0-12-generic/misc': No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [binary-modules] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/modules/penmountlpc'
make: *** [kdist_build] Error 2
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had success using the [source tarball](http://code.google.com/p/penmountlpc/downloads/detail?name=penmountlpc-source_1.1.tar.gz) instead of the Debian source package.

2. Get the source:

   ```
   wget "http://penmountlpc.googlecode.com/files/penmountlpc-source_1.1.tar.gz"
   tar xzvf penmountlpc-source_1.1.tar.gz
   cd penmountlpc-source-1.1/
   ```
3. Compile it (This requires [build-essential](http://packages.ubuntu.com/build-essential) [image: Install build-essential]):

   ```
   make
   ```
4. Install the kernel module:

   ```
   sudo make install
   sudo depmod
   ```
5. Verify that it loads successfully:

   ```
   sudo modprobe penmountlpc
   lsmod | grep penmountlpc
   ```
6. Configure Ubuntu to load it automatically at every boot:

   ```
   echo -e "\n# Linux kernel driver for the touchscreen on Dialogue Flybook notebooks\npenmountlpc" | sudo tee --append /etc/modules
   ```